# Appium: Exception: Invalid server instance exception has occured: There is no installed nodes

Tags: java, appium

I tried to start the appium server programmatically but encounter error. How to resolve this issues? I have nodejs installed and appium installed and environemnt variable set properly. I"m using maven appium java client 6.1.0 and selenium 3.14.0. Please help. A billion thanks for your help.

Code:

```
try {
            File appDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File app = new File(appDir, "..\\apk\\Flipkart.apk");

            // apk Capabilities
            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Sony Xperia Z2");
            caps.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
            caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.ANDROID);
            //caps.setCapability("udid", "WUJ01N4RQ3"); // DeviceId from "adb devices" command
            caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
            caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.flipkart.android");
            caps.setCapability("appActivity","com.flipkart.android.SplashActivity");

            // Appium Capabilities
            caps.setCapability("skipUnlock","true");
            caps.setCapability("noReset","false");

            appiumBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
            appiumBuilder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
            appiumBuilder.usingPort(47233);
            appiumBuilder.withCapabilities(caps);
            appiumBuilder.withStartUpTimeOut(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            appiumBuilder.withLogFile(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\log\\appium.log"));
            appiumBuilder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
            appiumBuilder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "DEBUG");
            appiumBuilder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.ASYNC_TRACE, "true");

            appiumServer = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(appiumBuilder);
            appiumServer.start();
            //new URL("http://127.0.0.1:47233/wd/hub")
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(appiumServer, caps);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogManager.logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Error Log:

> INFO: Exception: Invalid server instance exception has occured: There
>   is no installed nodes! Please install node via NPM
>   (https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium#using-node-js) or download and
>   install Appium app (http://appium.io/downloads.html) Jan 03, 2019
>   3:52:12 PM com.peterwkc.testManager.AndroidManager tearDown INFO:
>   Exception: null

EDIT: 
I believe appium source code cannot detect my installation of nodejs and appium.

Comment: Have you installed appium server in your  system? you must install appium server manually.

Comment: Installed already lol

Comment: can you post your error log?

Comment: Did you installed node.js in your system? Do npm -v shows npm version? If it is not showing the version then you must add the nodejs path in the system variable

Comment: Shows 6.4.1 version.

Answer (score 7):

Try installing Appium globally. This resolved the issue for me.

`npm install -g appium`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue at my end

1. Try to run the node server instance from command line, just type "node" and enter -- server should get started
2. Open another terminal window and just check if all details are been going good for the process running by doing "ps eww"
3. The node process running should be displayed here
4. Just kill the "node server", by typing "Killall node" on the same command window you did "ps eww"
5. The "node"window will show the process terminated.

Time for the truth, run your script and all should get going smoothly

I did this with 
appium - 1.9.0
node - 11.9.0
npm version - 6.5.0 
testscript - Java 
tool - Eclipse
platform - iOS (10.14)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when using `nvm` although `node` already installed on all versions.

Finally, I decided to [uninstall nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/298) and it's worked with the only `node` version

Answer (score 0):

•   Sometimes, when using Node Version Manager like **nvm** being used to install and maintain **node** and **npm**, you may need to download and install the same or higher version of **node/npm** being downloaded(in pkg form) from nodejs.org and update your PATH accordingly.