# Failed to instantiate Hooks class in Appium Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, appium

This question is my first on stackoverflow. I don't know English so I use translate. Sorry if I did something wrong. I want to work with Appium in Cucumber framework. I have a ready-made framework. However, when I want to run my tests, it gives an error in the Hooks class. It shows the error on the following line in the Hooks class:

```
private AppiumDriverLocalService appiumServer = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
```

I couldn't figure it out. Could you please help?
Thank you from now.

Error message in console:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Step failed
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepDefinitions.Hooks
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ObjectFactoryServiceLoader$DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(ObjectFactoryServiceLoader.java:140)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ObjectFactoryServiceLoader$DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(ObjectFactoryServiceLoader.java:124)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:59)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreHookDefinition.execute(CoreHookDefinition.java:46)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:21)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:92)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:64)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:98)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:71)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$5(Runtime.java:110)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:117)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$6(Runtime.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:86)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:204)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1361)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:87)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:92)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ObjectFactoryServiceLoader$DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(ObjectFactoryServiceLoader.java:132)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException: NodeJS is either not installed or its executable not present in PATH
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.validatePath(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:127)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.findBinary(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:137)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.findDefaultExecutable(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:87)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:83)
    at stepDefinitions.Hooks.<init>(Hooks.java:16)
    ... 36 more
```

Hooks class:

```
package stepDefinitions;

import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import utils.Driver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Hooks {
    
    private AppiumDriverLocalService appiumServer = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
    final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        
        forceStopAppiumServer();

        appiumServer.start();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) Driver.getAppiumDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "screenshots");
        }
        Driver.quitAppiumDriver();
        appiumServer.stop();
    }

    public void forceStopAppiumServer() {
        try {
            runtime.exec("killall node");
            runtime.exec("pkill  -i xcodebuild");
            System.out.println("Kill all nodes");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml file :

```
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jvm.options>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</jvm.options>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/runners/*TestRunner*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <forkMode>perthread</forkMode>
                    <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                    <argLine>-Duser.language=en</argLine>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                    <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/runners/*Runner*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <param>**/json-reports/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles><classificationFiles>->
                            <param>sample.properties</param>
                            <param>other.properties</param>
                        </classificationFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>


    </build>

</project>
```

JDK version on my computer 11 :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EtDU.png)

JDK version in project 1.8 :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2HWE.png)

I changed the JDK versions, I changed the versions of the dependencies in the pom.xml file, I even formatted the computer but I could not solve the problem.

Comment: *NodeJS is either not installed or its executable not present in PATH* have you checked it?

Comment: BTW: add the console output as  text not as image

Comment: @Jens Sorry for the late reply. Like I said, I'm new to this site.
I installed Node.js and set the path too, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Have you restarted  atleast your console after setting the path?

Comment: Yes, I even restarted the computer.

Comment: what is heppening if you call nodejs from your console?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand the question, but by this you mean [link](https://i.hizliresim.com/t5hr8nt.png)

Comment: Yes and you are sure it is exactly the same exception?

Comment: Yes, same exception. I can also post the console message here: [link](https://i.hizliresim.com/7mss3x2.png)

Comment: I need the end of the stacktrace

Comment: I added the entire console as an answer

Comment: *The main Appium script does not exist at 'C:\Users\Tarik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js'* it  is an other execption. looks like a problem with your configuration

Comment: So how can I solve it? Because I really don't know.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/12979) helps

Comment: The answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54017732/appium-exception-invalid-server-instance-exception-has-occured-there-is-no-in) solved my problem. Thank you very much. You made time for me, you tried to help me. These are priceless things. Thank you very much, I wish you success. Good bye.